# Rails login problems with different model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes

Firstly, I'm newbie to ROR.

I have a **User model**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation,:gender,:date,:username
  has_secure_password
end
```

and a **SessionsController** for signin/signout sessions with new,create and destroy methods :

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:sessions][:username])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
       sign_in
    else
       render sign_in page
    end
end
```

This implementation is not working with the **username atribute** of User model. but works well with the **email attribute**.(I'm able to sign in using email but not with username.)

when i run this in rails console it authenticates both for username and email attributes but on local server it just accepts the email attribute.

where am I going wrong?

Also I will also like to have something which will allow the user to sign i using either username or email. I tried this

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
      user = User.find_by_username(params[:sessions][:username]) or User.find_by_email(params[:sessions][:email])
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly strongly strongly suggest using something like Devise (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication, especially if you are new to RoR. There's so much to go wrong with authentication and it's such a critical part of your app that you should have a very good reason for trying to do it yourself.

Comment: I just current;y want to write authorization of my own.